# Is using PHPs exec function scale able and efficient for multi-processing?

Tags: php, asynchronous, multiprocessing, exec

I've become interested in async PHP and have researched things like pThreads, ReactPHP, Swoole and Amp. But I wanted to develop something similar myself rather then using something someone else built, just out of my own interest.

So my goal is to create the ability to write async code in PHP while keeping everything in a synchronous flow.

My idea is to use the exec function PHP provides and write a wrapper class which enables the use around exec().

For example if I wanted to perform a PDO SQL query, I could set off a background process via exec() which would set off another .php (CLI) file which would perform the PDO query but still letting the main PHP execution continue after exec() had completed... Using the command line arguments to send the SQL statement etc...

Then once the PDO query finishes it puts the result into a SESSION variable, allowing the main PHP request to either check if the result exists or get the result from the PDO database query.

I have not started anything yet, but I just want to know if something like this would be worth doing and would work while being scale able as if I got it stable enough, I would consider using it in a production environment.

Comment: Why not use something like AJAX?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Because I wanted to keep it server side?

Comment: @Erdss4 That's what using ajax would do without having to ping the server several times to see if the results are ready.

Comment: I am using a LAMP stack, so the reason for keeping it server side only was for every request that comes in, my idea was to use exec to set off child processes, run a load of other statements while a PDO query goes off and when im ready get the result from the session variable and then continue, alowing me to execute PDO queries int he background while I run other code, keeping PHP async in certain areas where I choose to use exec. If that makes sense?

Comment: Why do you want to write your own if there are well-working solutions and your goal is running it on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PHP's `exec` function *isn't* suited for multi-processing. It's blocking and thus only allows a single child process at a time. You can use `proc_open` instead to achieve what you want.

But if you goal is running on production, I'd really suggest using a [working solution](https://github.com/amphp/parallel) instead of building your own basis. Or do you like growing your own tree before building something using wood?

Comment: 'Or do you like growing your own tree before building something using wood?' Yes I do...

Comment: @Erdss4: You can of course do that, but it takes a long time. Anyway, your question is answered, `exec` isn't suited for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

@Erdss4, I think you don't really understand where is Async PHP used, and when is it useful for. (I don't want to offense you)

Let's imagine your situation:
classic php works like:

1. apache || nginx || other http server -> is listening for 80|443 incoming connections (requests).
2. on connection (request) it run (spawn, fork) php file that was routed, sending all incoming variables (cookies, post, get ...) to this php file.
3. php file has a clean context with only variables from last request, it runs all logic that was written, send back response and die (cleaning memory, context, ...) if we want to save something, we need some shared resources like RDB, NO-SQL, ... (classically running in another process, and accessed via TCP or php modules)
4. goto 1.

Async PHP works like:

1. php http server -> is listening for 80|443 incoming connections (requests), to write something like this there are some options, forking (slow, expensive), [event-loop](http://amphp.org/amp/event-loop/) (better), while(true) {} ...
2. now there is no nginx||apache who parse all incoming "variables" you must do it manually, [aerys](https://github.com/amphp/aerys)  can do this
3. you can write complex logic where context and variables can be shared among other requests without external resources like RDBs ...
4. but most powerful here are tools like [promises](http://amphp.org/amp/promises/) && [coroutines](http://amphp.org/amp/coroutines/)
5. remember your php is async only when all your external resources are accessed async

[amphp](https://github.com/amphp) has a lot of async components that permits to use the power of async php

P.S: My opinion: It make no sense to do what you want. Sorry.